# How to complete a script to move selective files and directories in a filesystem to another (dump) path in a different filesystem?

Tags: shell-script

1) There is a filesystem, say FS1, having below files and directories :

```
drwx------    2         256 Jun 20 05:47 recovery_scripts
drwx------    2         256 Jun 20 05:47 sqllib
-rw-------    1           1 Jun 20 05:47 dummy
drwx------    2         256 Jun 20 05:47 lost+found
-rw-------    1           1 Jun 20 05:48 test
-rw-------    1           1 Jun 20 07:38 LAES201D.LOG
```

2) I want to move specific files and directories to another filesystem, say FS2, viz. :

```
drwx------    2         256 Jun 20 05:47 recovery_scripts
drwx------    2         256 Jun 20 05:47 sqllib
-rw-------    1           1 Jun 20 05:47 dummy
-rw-------    1           1 Jun 20 07:38 LAES201D.LOG
```

3) Rest of the files should remain in FS1 itself :

```
drwx------    2         256 Jun 20 05:47 lost+found
-rw-------    1           1 Jun 20 05:48 test
```

4) I want to come up with a script for the same.
Please help.

Comment: Why do you need a script? It is only a one line command to do this `cd /FS2;mv recovery_scripts sqllib dummy LAES201D.LOG /FS1`. If you need it scripted, then add a line to the top such as `#!/bin/bash` followed by the code and it will run if you need it to run multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with bash

```
mv FS1/!(test|lost+found) FS2/
```